# How to plot a Flow Map in R using GPS Trajectory Data?

Tags: r, geospatial, data-science

I have the following GPS Trajectory Data (fraction of the whole dataset):

```
# safegraph_id  latitude    longitude   horizontal_accuracy id_type utc_timestamp   geo_hash
# ef3a28742059bdcd65aad91ab77ffc180956b13336e93c2b75a1c6dbc56db0e1  18.458185   -66.731697  8   idfa    1506268248  de2912pqw
# 72860c415b90a7788dcfd0de748181b37f6878ba09c50ab36ddf142c82febf3d  18.412485   -66.119324  120.5433266 idfa    1505389477  de2bxrvkk
# 431e6e49111f1f7a49b9cda05f1b016f6e006b2b4c4f5b1d45a33cd65a0a4abe  18.314985   -66.091981  6   idfa    1504664544  de300n1k9
# 431e6e49111f1f7a49b9cda05f1b016f6e006b2b4c4f5b1d45a33cd65a0a4abe  18.414039   -66.103403  6   idfa    1505101204  de2bzb0vx
```

I'm new with R and I would like to plot a flow map so I can see the movement of the population. I have looked through some examples but is a little difficult to understand since the data used is different. Can somebody help me with this? I need to know what do I need from dataset to make the plot. Thank you.

Comment: Can you include a fraction of your data with `dput(data)` to your question.  What were the examples you looked at, what  is the difficult part and how should the plot look like?

Comment: Some of the examples that I looked involve origin and destination points and my dataset shows the location of each user with no specific destination. I'm thinking that in order to plot a flow map, I will need to cluster the points, identify each cluster and then get the frequency of the trips between the clusters.

Comment: Yeah, a flow has per definition a start and an end. Maybe you can also use the timestamps per user for that.. That could indicate an origin and destination..

Comment: Thanks! I may have an idea on how to arrange the origin and destination points using the datadr package.